# Empty css after heroku deployment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am not familiar to `heroku`. I have a rails app working fine on local. When I deploy it on remote, I get no css loaded. I can see the `css` file in my console, but it is empty.

I am using Rails 5 and ruby 2.4.6. Does someone has an idea ?

Comment: We can't help you with code we can't see. You have over 5k reputation; you should know this. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason for this is the fact that in the local environment, the assets can be retrieved directly from the asset pipeline/webpacker.

On heroku the app server is running on production environment and only loads the compiled static files for js/css/images/fonts.

Try running the below code from your console.

```
heroku run rails console
rails_env=production rake assets:precompile
heroku restart
```

P.S In case this does not work there must be a setting in production.rb called fallback to asset_pipeline something like this. Set it to true. Not recommended though.